# Can there be an unbounded sequence of equicontinuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am trying to find a equicontinuous sequence of functions $f_n$ on $(a, b)$ that is bounded somewhere but not everywhere.

I am thinking along the lines of 
$$f_n=\frac{1}{nx}$$ on $(0, 1)$, but this is obviously not equicontinuous.

Any hints?

Comment: does $f_n(x)=n$ work?

Comment: @illysial Oh, sorry, I was trying to find a sequence that is bounded somewhere on the domain but not everywhere. I've edited the question.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what "bounded somewhere but not everywhere" means?

Answer (score 0):

I understand/interpret your question as follows: You want to find
an equicontinuous sequence $\left(f_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
of functions $f_{n}:\left(0,1\right)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that the
set
$$
U:=\left\{ x\in\left(0,1\right)\,\middle|\,\exists M_{x}\in\left(0,\infty\right)\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\,\left|f_{n}\left(x\right)\right|\leq M_{x}\right\} 
$$
is not empty, but also not all of $\left(0,1\right)$.

As we will see now, such a sequence does not exist. To see this, we
will show that $U$ is both open and closed in $\left(0,1\right)$.
By connectedness of $\left(0,1\right)$, this implies $U\in\left\{ \emptyset,\left(0,1\right)\right\} $.

1. $U$ is open: Let $x_{0}\in U$ be arbitrary. By equicontinuity,
   there is $\varepsilon>0$ (potentially depending on $x_{0}$) with
   $\left(x_{0}-\varepsilon,x_{0}+\varepsilon\right)\subset U$ and with
   $\left|f_{n}\left(x_{0}\right)-f_{n}\left(y\right)\right|<1$ for
   all $y\in\left(x_{0}-\varepsilon,x_{0}+\varepsilon\right)$. But this
   implies
   $$
   \left|f_{n}\left(y\right)\right|\leq\left|f_{n}\left(x_{0}\right)\right|+1\leq M_{x_{0}}+1
   $$
   for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so that we get $\left(x_{0}-\varepsilon,x_{0}+\varepsilon\right)\subset U$.
2. $U$ is closed in $\left(0,1\right)$. To see this, let $x_{0}\in\overline{U}\cap\left(0,1\right)$.
   By equicontinuity, there is $\varepsilon>0$ with $\left(x_{0}-\varepsilon,x_{0}+\varepsilon\right)\subset U$
   and with $\left|f_{n}\left(x_{0}\right)-f_{n}\left(y\right)\right|<1$
   for all $y\in\left(x_{0}-\varepsilon,x_{0}+\varepsilon\right)$. But
   since $x_{0}\in\overline{U}$, there is some $y\in U\cap\left(x_{0}-\varepsilon,x_{0}+\varepsilon\right)$.
   This implies
   $$
   \left|f_{n}\left(x_{0}\right)\right|\leq\left|f_{n}\left(y\right)\right|+1\leq M_{y}+1
   $$
   for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, $x_{0}\in U$.